# LocalTime range query with MongoDB (Java)

Tags: mongodb, morphia

Would this work with MongoDB Java Driver?

```java
class Hub {
    List<Schedule> schedules; 
}
```

```
class Schedule {
    String day;
    LocalTime opens;
    LocalTime closes;
}
```

And then query those *Hubs*  which opens and closes during a specific day, say, query with this constraint:

```java
new Schedule().builder()
    .day("Monday")
    .opens(LocalTime.parse("08:00")
    .close(LocalTime.parse("17:00").build();
```

*Note that LocalTime is not Date*

So in this case we want to query for *Hubs* that are open on Mondays at 8am to 5pm.
**How does this translate to MongoDB Java Query?**